# Strange Behaviour with Flat File Import

Tags: sql-server, ssis, text-files

0I am importing a text file encoded in UTF8 - without BOM usign a flat file source to OLE DATABASE task .

Format of Flat file connection is DELIMITED, 65001(UTF-8), Text Qualifier ( none ) , Header Row delimiter is {CR}{LF} , Header Rows skip is 2 , and the column names in the first data row . Row Delimiter is {CR}{LF} and column Delimiter is Vertical Bar {|}.

Format of data is like so ;

SPECIAL products in q: Reported on 01/11/2011 {CR}{LF}

{CR}{LF}

Serve|Co|Q Number|Doc Name|{CR}{LF}

HE| AUS|000021|Dert|{CR}{LF}

The problem is that SSIS is not seeing the first 112 rows ? I cant work this out . It is driving me crazy so pl help ?

All the other rows in the fiel starting from 113 import into the database with no problems. No errors when SSIS package runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the "Header Rows to Skip" property? Whats the value there?
Also, if you look at the "Preview" of the data in the FF Connection manager, there's a property called "Data Rows to skip". Both these properties should be 0's. What do you see on your FF manager?

Comment: Ah! I read your question again. You seem to skip first 2 rows. What would you get if you dont skip the first 2?

Comment: property called "Data Rows to skip". was the PROBLEM . Thanks. I did not set it . That is proper strange !